# Swift Generic is treated as a parent in typealias

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias

I have a method:

```
public func someMethod<Controller>(controller: Controller) {
    print(controller)

    typealias HandlerType = Controller -> UIViewController
    let handler: HandlerType

    print(handler.dynamicType)
}
```

After calling it with the instance of child of UIViewController, which is ViewController in my case, it prints:

```
<Test.ViewController: 0x7fc43be479d0>
UIViewController -> UIViewController
```

What is my goal is to have a typealias like this:

```
Test.ViewController -> UIViewController
```

I have typealias and the declared valriable:

```
public typealias ControllerType = UIViewController 
public private(set) static var visibleController: ControllerType?
```

And the method invocation is:

```
if let controller = visibleController { 
    someMethod(controller) 
}
```

I do not understand why ViewController becomes UIViewController in typealias, so if anyone faced with such kind of an issue, and/or have a solution, Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that your complete code? It seems to me that this would happen with generic constraints such as `Controller: UIViewController`.

Comment: Actually for this example it doesn't matter. For my code it was like you are saying, I just changed it to be sure it do not works even in this case.

Comment: You're having a type system issue. I would encourage you to be accurate about types in your example, even if you think that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the static and dynamic type of your `controller` differ.

The static type is taken from your `ControllerType` typealias, which you've defined to be `UIViewController`. The dynamic type is the same type as the instance that `visibleController` points to – in this case `Test.ViewController`.

Because generics are inferred from the static type that you pass into the function (their specialisation takes place at compile-time), `Controller` will be inferred to be `UIViewController`. Therefore your typealias will be `UIViewController -> UIViewController`, and that's what `dynamicType` of your `handler` will return (it appears to fallback to the static type when unassigned).

On the other hand, the dynamic type of your `controller` will indeed be `Test.ViewController`, as that's the `dynamicType` of the instance that you pass in.

As for solutions, without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve here, it's hard to say.